GitHub / VS 2022 not showing work items after issue 270 or so?
Has anyone seen an issue with VS 2022 and GitHub with not showing related items in the IDE?
I've made a new branch to add a new page. When I try to check my code in with the issue # I made, it doesn't work?
I go to issue #270 and it works?
I've googled a few things and I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working?
#270 works:

The one I just created #286 does not?

Issue created in GitHub website:

VS version:
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022
Version 17.9.5
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.9.5+34723.18
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.09032
Installed Version: Professional

I wonder if the PR has to be merged in first.

@TimothyG: The work item is closed now and it still doesn't work :-(

I'm out of ideas. I don't really use any of the git tools in Visual Studio. There are far better tools for working with git and github

@TimothyG.: Yea, this is in VS 2022 working with on old Vb.net application and then .NET 8 WEB API. So I have to use VS 2022 for the most part.

@TimothyG: I posted they answer! I put a ticket in with the dev community VS and they fixed it in the new upcoming release.

This issue appears to be fixed in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-preview#17100-pre40--visual-studio-2022-version-1710-preview-4
I downloaded VS 2022 preview and it works now!
Not sure when they will push it to VS 2022 regular.
